# Built-in ways to detect keystrokes

Tags: python

I have been looking through so many questions exactly like this, but I have yet to find an answer. I have looked through [this](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/library#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time), but it is really complicated, and I don't know how to run my application while detecting keystrokes this way. Is there a built in python module for detecting keystrokes in a way that is threaded (sorry if that's the wrong term) so I don't have to keep checking in a while loop?

Comment: Is this in a terminal, or in general?

Comment: yep in a terminal, but if there is a general case (I know modules like Tkinter and pygame have their own key press methods) I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Basically, you can also select on stdin and read one char, if you have an event loop.

Comment: are you looking to capture letter/number/special keys? if so, you could write something using raw_input or input (depending on python version), but if your looking or something that will catch things like f1-12 and such, you may be better off looking at a gui framework, not for the GUI parts, but just for the keystroke parts.

Comment: Yeah I would like all keys available to me :) thanks for the replys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module **on UNIX**. AFAIK there is no platform-independent *module* for doing what you want.

If you want something simple and that works everywhere it's probably better to use a GUI library such as `Qt`, `Wx` or `Gtk`. This does not mean that you have to write a full GUI for your program, but it isn't too hard to use the gui's event loop to catch keystrokes.
For `Qt` you could use a `QCoreApplication` for example.

There are some ways to achieve what you want without external dependencies, for example [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/) recipe which uses `msvcrt` on windows and `tty`, `termios` and `sys` on UNIX, but, since you complained about their complexity you're probably better with a gui toolkit.